Use multiple nested object information to generate documents using Salesforce OmniStudio
I am trying to configure Omnistudio to generate a document using fields from multiple objects listed as follows.

Account-->Order-->Order Line Item --> Invoice

Here is the SOQL query that I want the Extract dataraptor to be based on.

SELECT Id,
(SELECT Id,
(SELECT Id, blng__TotalBilling__c,
(SELECT Id, blng__Payments__c, blng__Balance__c
FROM blng__OrderProductInvoiceLines__r)
FROM OrderItems)
FROM Orders)
FROM Account
WHERE Id ='Id of the Account'

Can someone help me understand how should I setup the nested object query in the Extract tab of the Extract Data Raptor? Appreciate any suggestions/pointers.
Thank you!!
